# Visual bug on tabs with bounty questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When looking at the front page, the Featured tab looks like this:

[image]

When I browse to the Featured tab, it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how there are artifacts outside of the red oval.

I'm running Safari 5 on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Looks much better now.  Thank you!